# pandasql::sqldf not capturing looping variable

Tags: python, sql, pandas, pandasql

I'm trying to loop over a list with pandasql::sqldf but this sqldf does not seem to be capturing the looping variable. Below is a stylized outline of my problem:

```
import pandas as pd
from pandasql import sqldf
from datetime import datetime

FreqGamePlay = pd.DataFrame({'CONTACT_WID' : [1, 2, 3, 1, 4], 
                         'TITLE_NOMIN_DT' : pd.to_datetime(['20130102', '20140103', '20120518', 
                                        '20140317', '20111123']),
                        'FreqGamePlay' : [12, 9, 22, 4, 5]})
FreqGamePlay = FreqGamePlay[['CONTACT_WID', 'TITLE_NOMIN_DT', 'FreqGamePlay']]

periodsList = ['2012-12-26', '2012-02-28']
for i in periodsList:
    temp = sqldf("select CONTACT_WID, sum(FreqGamePlay) as FGP from FreqGamePlay where TITLE_NOMIN_DT > i group by CONTACT_WID;", globals())
    print(temp)
```

above program gives the following error:

> PandaSQLException: (sqlite3.OperationalError) no such column: i [SQL:      'select CONTACT_WID, sum(FreqGamePlay) as FGP from FreqGamePlay where TITLE_NOMIN_DT > i group by CONTACT_WID;']

but if I hard-code the date by hand it works fine:

```
for i in periodsList:
    temp = sqldf("select CONTACT_WID, sum(FreqGamePlay) as FGP from FreqGamePlay where TITLE_NOMIN_DT > '2012-12-26' group by CONTACT_WID;", globals())
    print(temp)
```

But above is not efficient as the actual program has a much larger list of dates. Any suggestions appreciated, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you included the “i” variable directly in your SQL string so Python assumes it’s part of the string and the variables does not get evaluated (you can notice that in the error message the i variable is not replaced by its value). I suggest you read a bit about working with Python strings and variables. Until then, try this:

```
for i in periodsList:
    query = "select CONTACT_WID, sum(FreqGamePlay) as FGP from FreqGamePlay where TITLE_NOMIN_DT > '{}' group by CONTACT_WID;".format(i)
    temp = sqldf(query, globals())
```

The curly braces serve as a placeholder for your variable and the format() method is there to replace the placeholder by the variable value.